# Git Smart HTTP(S) with a URL redirect, not working

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, git

I am trying to have [GitList](http://gitlist.org/) (PHP web viewer for git) and GIT Smart HTTP(S) under the same domain git.domain.ext. The following is the actual setup:

- GIT Smart HTTP URLs are the form git.domain.ext/git/reponame.git
- GitList is served through git.domain.ext/gitlist

So far, so good. Everything works.

What I would like to achieve is the following:

- Any request of the form git.domain.ext/*.git should instead go to git.domain.ext/git/*.git
- Any other request should default to git.domain.ext/gitlist

The following is my Apache config:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName git.domain.ext
    DocumentRoot /home/user/www/git.domain.ext

    SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/user/git/
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

    ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/

    <Location />
            AuthName "Git Authentication"
            AuthType Basic
            Require valid-user
            AuthUserFile /home/user/git/.htpasswd
    </Location>
    <LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Git Access"
            Require valid-user
            AuthUserFile /home/user/git/.htpasswd
    </LocationMatch>
    [..]
 </VirtualHost>
```

The following is the .htaccess under /home/user/www/git.domain.ext

```
AuthName "Git Authentication"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
AuthUserFile /home/user/git/.htpasswd


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.git
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.git /git/$1.git [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*) /gitlist/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Git operations with the original /git/*.git work:

```
git clone https://user@git.domain.ext/git/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
Password for 'https://user@git.domain.ext':
remote: Counting objects: 343, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (322/322), done.
remote: Total 343 (delta 110), reused 149 (delta 12)
Receiving objects: 100% (343/343), 1.13 MiB | 1.36 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (110/110), done.
```

Unfortunately, git operations with the wanted /*.git don't work:

```
git clone https://git.domain.ext/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
Password for 'https://user@git.domain.ext':
fatal: https://user@git.domain.ext/test.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

However, it seems that the redirect works:

```
curl --user user:pass https://git.domain.ext/test.git

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://git.domain.ext/git/test.git">here</a>.</p>
[..]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, it is **always** a mod_rewrite error :-)

To make work, I used the following in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.git
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.git /git/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) /gitlist/ [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem was in the previous `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.git /git/$1.git [R=301,L]`, which was generating 404 errors. Strangely enough, I could spot them only using --verbose with curl.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, git as a client doesn't handle redirects. Is there any reason you want that rewrite to happen as a redirect rather than as a silent rewrite (i.e. without the `R=302` option)?

Comment: No reason at all. I am not an expert on this stuff. Unfortunately, removing the R option (thus, keeping only [L]) does not solve the problem. curl reports a 302 to /git/test.git but git clone fails with the same message (keeping /test.gif in the error message).